# Is there a way to display vertical indent lines in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Is there any way to persuade the Delphi IDE to display vertical indent lines that help me see which begin goes with which end? I would like the IDE option to show a vertical line between associated begin/end statements.

Comment: This is possible with CnPack's IDE wizard plugins, or with some third-party IDE enhancement packages. It's not part of the IDE itself.

Comment: So anyway.... +1 for CNPack.  It gives the vertical lines, brace/bracket matching, etc.. It's also got features that you probably already have, such as line numbers, so you'll want to turn some features off.

Comment: For anyone interested, I asked about answer deletion on meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186444/why-was-this-answer-which-seemed-good-to-me-deleted-by-a-diamond-mod

Comment: OK, I think with the edits here we've got ourselves a perfectly viable question. As a result, I've reopened it and cleaned up the debate in the comments to keep things focused on the issue at hand.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the [CnPack IDE Wizards](http://code.google.com/p/cnpack/), this plugin includes a feature called `Code Structure Highlight`.

[image]

Comment: Very glad I stumbled across this.  The plugin is fantastic! :D

Answer (score 2):

In Delphi 10 Seattle and later it is a built in function and by default turned on.

[image: Look here.]